# I can't remove the navigation bars in beamer

Tags: beamer, navigation

I fail to get rid of the navigation bars in beamer by using `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}` or `\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty`.

[image]

Here is the key source codes.

```
%\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\usetheme{Warsaw} 

\title[<short version fore footer>]{<long version for titlepage>}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
%\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=scriptsize,labelfont=scriptsize}

\usepackage{tabularx} %for automatic line-break in tabular
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{makecell}  %for table header, center and bold
```

PS: My environment is: Ubuntu + texlive.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: It is compilable in my machine.

Comment: @SparkandShine -- No, it is not compilable.  Only complete files are compilable, which means they (if LaTeX) start at `\documentclass`, and include both `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.    Everything else is just a code snippet, and usually do not form the basis of good questions.

Comment: @jon  in my opinion, Questioner is obligated to simplify the question by getting rid of unrelated info.

Comment: I'm afraid your opinion does not, in general, reflect a useful way to get help or make it easy for others to help you. The consensus on this site is that including a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) is almost always the best way to ask a question.  If you read some of the first comments to a huge number of the questions here, you'll see a comment similar to the one @samcarter left you. Often, if a person is asking a question, they don't know what is too much or too little information, but both are problematic from the perspective of those trying to help.

Comment: @jon thx for this update. I will keep in mind. nice weekend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the modification for templates *after* loading the theme:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw} 

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}

\title[<short version fore footer>]{<long version for titlepage>}

\begin{document}

\section{A test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Some remarks:

1- Better not to use the `caption` package with `beamer`.

2- `beamer` already internally loads `hyperref`, no need to load it explicitly.